# InternetCrackUrl curl alternative

Tags: libcurl

I am looking for curl aternative to Wininet InternetCrackUrl.
if not curl any function which splits the url will work .
Pointers around this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the functions from urlapi.h, just add `#include <curl/urlapi.h>`. cURL is more object-oriented than Win32 API. You create URL object on the first step and then you can manipulate URL parts.

```c
char *path = NULL;
CURLU *url = curl_url();
curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_URL, "https://example.com/path/to/file", 0);
curl_url_get(url, CURLUPART_HOST, &path, CURLU_URLDECODE);
curl_url_cleanup(url);
```

The above example is equivalent of

```c
char *path = NULL;
LPURL_COMPONENTS parts = {0};
InternetCrackUrl("https://example.com/path/to/file", 0, ICU_DECODE, &parts);
path = parts.lpszUrlPath;
```

More info: [URL API](https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/url)

Comment: that is what i was looking for . thanks a ton.